# Passing a selected object from child region to parent (PRISM)

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

We want to pass a selected object inside a child region back to the parent

What we have is a view for selecting a new object (IClient) and assign a text reason why this object has been added.  To select the new object we have another view that contains a DataGrid of the objects.

```
<StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Label}" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtText}"/>
        <!-- Client View-->
        <Label Content="{Binding ReasonLabel}" Target="{Binding ElementName=TxtReason}"/>
        <TextBox Name="TxtReason" Text="{Binding Reason}"/>
        <Button Content="Ok" Command="{Binding OkCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

I would like to be able to double click the object in the child view and that would set the relevant property on the parent view (in this case IClient)

Comment: What exactly is your question? Can you explain why you can't just set a property on your object and be done with it?